# Веб-приложение PHP+MYSQL+JS

Tags: php, jquery

Обращаюсь к профессионалам в веб-разработке.
Пишу небольшое приложение на php. Много работы с БД, много подгружаемой информации, и уже несколько десятков функций JQuery на onclick. Спрашиваю больше для успокоения - это нормально? просто получается что сайт больше на JS, чем на php :) 
Когда смотришь чужие java скрипты, там вроде по умному, куча функций всяких, а у меня 90% обработка кликов. Может посоветуете чего.

Сам по себе прикладной программист. Немного не укладывается в голове обработка JS. Всегда казалось, что это слишком нагружает процессор (хотя в отладке не наблюдаю такового).

Comment: Сейчас тенденция такая. Очень много работы приложения переносится на клиент. Сервер же просто отдает данные клиентскому приложению.

Comment: Так зависит от сайта. Если серверной логики не так много, само собой, клиент может перевесить. По моему, `JS` и нужен, чтобы хэндлить события на клиенте, клики неклики и прочие вещи. `JS` может занимать значительную часть проекта, если там учтено немало нюансов клиентской логики. Единственное, что могу заметить - это если все эти несколько десятков функций реализуются на одной странице.